# Kendo data attribute initialization not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendonumerictextbox

I'm creating a numeric text box with data attributes for the initialization but it does not seem to be working, can someone help to explain why or is this just a Kendo UI bug please?

([documentation of how to use data attribute initialization](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/data-attribute-initialization#configuration))

[demo of working example](http://dojo.telerik.com/OCAfA/2)

[demo of non-working example](http://dojo.telerik.com/OCAfA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can mix the usage of data- attributes, and javascript kendo widget creation.

You need to either create the object using javascript with all options set, or use data- attributes to define the widget and options, and a kendo.bind to create them.  See sample.

http://dojo.telerik.com/OCAfA/3